# How to make last child in ul expand to the remaining width of browser

Tags: css, html-lists

I have three list items with a specific color to each list item and they are floated to left. The ul in container. I need the last child in ul to expand to the remaining width of browser in all sizes.

```css
.my-list li:first-child:before{
        content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  right: 100%;
  top: 0;
  background-color: inherit;
}
.my-list li:last-child:after{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
  background-color: inherit;
}
```

```html
<ul class="my-list">
  <li><a href="#">first list item</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Second list item</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Third list item</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: flexbox can easily solve this.

Comment: @CBroe ...and it does.. :)

Answer (score 1):

Flexbox can do that with a pseudo-element.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  overflow-X: hidden; /* no nasty scrollbar */
}
.container {
  width: 60%;
  margin: auto;
  border:1px solid red;
}
.my-list {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
}
li {
  padding: 0 1em;
  background: pink;
}
.my-list li:last-child {
  flex: 1;
  background: lightgreen;
  position: relative;
}
.my-list li:last-child:after {
  content: "";
  background: inherit;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul class="my-list">
    <li><a href="#">first list item</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Second list item</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Third list item</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. but I need it to flex out of the container. 
for example container is 940px 
I need it to expand to the full width of browser

Comment: Updated with solution on similar lines to your starting point.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
  .my-list li:last-child{
  width: 100%;
  background-color: initial;
}
```

You can change the background-color to see it working